# How to set position of a block at top-right with freewall.js?

Tags: javascript, html, freewalljs

I am facing a problem with **freewall.js**.

I want to set the position of a specific element at top-right, but the only options i found in the docs are for top-left positioning.

```
<div class="freewall">
    <div class="freewall-item js-frontpage-teaser-slider frontpage-teaser-slider">
        {{ render_esi(controller( "sf.fnma.controller.frontpage:renderAdBanner")) }}
    </div>
    <div class="freewall-item mx-auto sidebar-banner" data-fixPos="top-right">
        {% include 'teaser/frontpage.html.twig' %}
    </div>
        {{ render_esi(controller( "sf.fnma.controller.frontpage:renderEvents")) }}
        {{ render_esi(controller("sf.fnma.controller.frontpage:renderNews")) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried the fixPos() method and the data attributes data-positon and data-fixPos, but i'm not able to achieve the result i want.

Comment: You may need to add a few more details in order to get help with this.  For instance providing a [CodePen](https://codepen.io) link which includes the specific js/css libraries required to reproduce your issue.

Comment: What information do you need? Everything you need is there, as long as you know freewall.js. My Problem is that there is only one option for positioning -> top-left and i need top-right and i don't know how to achieve this.